# QSqlQuery: get prepared statement string before execution

Tags: c++, qt, qsqlquery, qtsql

For testing purposes, I'm trying to get the prepared statement string out of a `QSqlQuery` object before actually running it.

I have checked `lastQuery()` and `executedQuery()` methods, but none of them work.

```
void foo(QSqlQuery& q)
{
    QString statement = q.lastQuery();
    // statement is empty unless exec() is called
}

QSqlQuery q(myDb);
q.prepare("SELECT * FROM Foo;");
foo(q);
```

I'd like a way to get back the `prepare()` parameter string.

Comment: what abount "boundValues()"? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#boundValues

Comment: I want the full string `SELECT * FROM Foo;` not just the values bound to placeholders.

Comment: I'm afraid the solution is to obtain the bound values and replace question marks with the bound values.

Comment: The example has no bound values or question marks, still `lastQuery` returns an empty string. Indeed, the statement with question marks would be valid for my current use case, but I found no method that returns the string **before** running `exec()`

Comment: Me neither. I would store the statement in a local string and obtain the boundvalues right before the executation after binding them and recreate the statement by using the string and question mark replacement. I don't see another option.

Comment: Why do you need it before execution? You can't do anything with it anyway, short of having your own SQL parser...

Comment: @KubaOber in my design, one class is responsible for composing the SQL statements and pass a QSqlQuery object to another that actually executes them. I'd like the latter to perform some minimal validation on the query before actually executing it.

Comment: Well, so you need an SQL parser then, and doing such substitutions will be not a problem for it :)

Comment: @KubaOber yes, but I do need to get the statement out of the `QSqlQuery` object in order to parse it, which is what I'm asking if possible :)

Comment: It's possible as long as you represent the query as your own data structure. You shouldn't be using `QSqlQuery` until your composition and validation is done. `QSqlQuery` is not really designed well to be a high-level query manipulation tool. It's a way to submit a query for execution, and that's about it.

Comment: @KubaOber thanks, that sounds good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a look at the Qt source code, I found where the string ends up in the `prepare` method:

```
...
if (query.isEmpty()) {
    qWarning("QSqlQuery::prepare: empty query");
    return false;
}
#ifdef QT_DEBUG_SQL
    qDebug("\n QSqlQuery::prepare: %s",query.toLocal8Bit().constData());
#endif
return d->sqlResult->savePrepare(query);
```

In which `sqlResult` is a private `QSqlQueryPrivate` object. So I would say it might be complicated to get the string from there.

However, a solution comes to my mind. Subclass `QSqlQuery`, setting a `QString` attribute which will hold the prepared statement. Then redefine the `QSqlQuery::prepare()` so it stores the value in the attribute, and then does the original job:

```
bool TestQSqlQuery::prepare(const QString& query){
    this->m_preparedQuery = query;
    return QSqlQuery::prepare(query);
}
```

Then create a `getPreparedQuery` method to retrieve the value at any given time.

I don't think it is a 'clean' solution, but it might help you nonetheless.

Comment: Can't you just change private to protected/public in the header?

Answer (score -1):

```
q.executedQuery();
```

Will return prepared query.

Comment: OP said that `executedQuery` does not work in his case, because he needs the query string **before** execution.